# How to prove the sums have not the same sign.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)_{n\ge 0}$ be a non periodic sequence of elements in $\{0,1\}$.

Could we prove that The sums
$$\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^{a_i}$$
and
$$\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^{i+a_i}$$

have not necessarily the same sign at least for large enough $n$.

Comment: It seems to be an interesting question, but what made you to post it as a PSQ?

Answer (score 0):

If the $a_i$'s are mostly $0$'s with an occasional $1$, then the first sum will diverge to $+\infty$. If the occasional $1$'s all appear at *even* values of $i$, then the second sum will diverge to $-\infty$.

On the other hand, if the occasional $1$'s all appear at *odd* values of $i$, the second sum will also diverge to $+\infty$. In general, by modulating the parity of where the $1$'s occasionally appear, you can get the second sum to do pretty much whatever you want.

Comment: This is a special case. thanks.